# Check which classes in a jar extend an abstract class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am wondering if there is a way to check: for an abstract class, which classes extend the abstract class.

I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Did you check for [this guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search__Go_to_Implementation.html)

Comment: You could search all the files that contains extends <abstract class>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any class to show the type hierarchy (super- and/or subclasses), position the cursor on the class name and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. This will show the tree of type hierarchy. You can toggle between showing sub-classes, super-classes and both.

Alternatively (thanks, @maydawn!) you can click the icon to the left of the line with the class name to show a popup with a list of sub-classes.

[image: Type hierarchy]

Comment: It is also possible to just click the small icon to the left of the class / interface declaration to see implementations

Comment: @maydawn thanks for pointing it out, I incorporated your hint in my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to or can generate the JavaDocs for the Jar, there should be a listing of all subclasses. For an example of this, see [AbstractAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractAction.html) which has many subclasses.

One warning with this method is that it only shows direct subclasses, though this shouldn't be a serious limitation for most code bases with relatively shallow inheritance trees.